# Do-loop ignores if-statement

Tags: if-statement, fortran, do-loops

I'm trying to use an if statement in a do loop which is supposed to generate prime numbers. For that I used `modulo` to sort out the numbers. After it found a prime number I want it to go a step further and add 1 so that the next prime number can be found and added to the array `pzahl`. My problem is that the loop seems to ignore that it should go a step further with `plauf` after it found a prime number so that it just keeps going till infinity... I tried to rearrange the contents of the loop and if statement but it's just not working. Here is the code:

```
PROGRAM Primzahlen

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER :: start, plauf, n, a
   INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: pzahlen !array into which the  prime numbers should be added
   INTEGER :: input
   INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: alle 

   PRINT *, "How many prime numbers should be listed"
   READ (*,*) input
   ALLOCATE (pzahlen(input))
   pzahlen(1) = 1 
   start = 2
   plauf = 1

 loop1: DO 

   ALLOCATE(alle(start))

    loop2: DO n = 1,start
       alle(n)= MODULO(start,n)
    END DO loop2

   IF (minval(alle) /= 0) THEN  ! This is what it seems to ignore.
    plauf= plauf + 1 
    pzahlen(plauf) = start
    PRINT *, plauf
   END IF

  start = start + 1

 IF (plauf == eingabe) then
    EXIT
 END IF
 PRINT *,  alle
 DEALLOCATE(alle)

END DO loop1

PRINT *, "prime numbers:" , pzahlen(1:input)

END PROGRAM Primzahlen
```

I use the gfortran compiler and write it in Emacs if that helps to know.

Comment: Shouldn’t you END DO loop1?

Comment: the END DO loop1 is at the ending. But I'm not entirely sure if I should rather use it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ignoring it, it executes correctly:

```
loop2: DO n = 1,start
   alle(n)= MODULO(start,n)
END DO loop2
```

It doesn't matter what `start` is, `alle(1)` will always be zero, as every integer is evenly divisible by 1. That means that `minval(alle)` will also always be zero, which means that the condition `minval(alle) /= 0` is never true, and the statement will never execute.

Added: The last value, `alle(start)`, will also be zero, as every number is evenly divisible by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've change that and now it at least works half ways. Although it still isn't perfect yet.

Comment: There are several things in your code that are unnecessary computation. For example, you always check *all* numbers, whereas you could stop after the first match. And if you haven't found a divisor by the time you reach the square root of the target, you can stop, as there won't be any larger one.

Comment: I'll ad an if statement to loop2 to avoid that. I just started learning Fortran so it's nice of you to help out :)